# Would a poll on the most influential hacker movies be appropriate?

Tags: discussion, scope

Not all hacker movies are science-fiction, but a large percentage of them are. Would this poll be appropriate for the site?

Answer (score 19):

Well, polls in general are not really what we look for here, so I would say no on that basis.

Beyond that:

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask